# PayPal REST API with intent sale: Open credit card payment by default

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm using the PayPal REST API to direct payers from our site to the PayPal site to make payment. It opens with the "Pay with my PayPal account" as the default option, can this be changed to default to "Pay with a debit or credit card"?

I've seen a couple of responses that have suggested using "LANDINGPAGE" but this seems to be only applicable with the Classic API not the REST API.

Is there a REST API equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now the PayPal offers the similar functionality in the REST API also . You can check the below link for more information :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest-experience-overview/